# How to setup and configure Proxy Server in Linux box for a network?

Tags: networking, proxy, ip, squid

In Ubuntu, I am going to start Squid and Squish for proxy setup, but have problems in squid to make every workstation use proxy. Setup and configuration of squid is working properly, for testing purpose manual proxy address is working in my workstation, but how to make it possible for other workstations?

Also, I have to setup proxy when user click on automatically detect proxy setup then it works, I'll try to find a lot of stuff regarding this but didn't understand properly.

In `squid.conf` file,  I'll set `acl localnet 10.0.23.0/24` and allow `http_access`, after this set own IP address in manual proxy tab and it works, but not for all other systems which exist in our subnetwork.

Its like I have to setup a proxy server on my system and set for all other workstations.